# CSS dropdown menu - incorect submenu size

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

Im making a css horizontal nav menu.
How can i make the submenus width to adjust automaticly to its content?
like the main menu does.

My css: http://pastebin.com/Kpx4s3fH

The text just folds back down.

EDIT: and the html http://pastebin.com/xaC0kvud

Comment: need more code.  That's just the CSS.  We also need the markup and preferably using the Code Snippet (Ctrl-m) in the editor.

Comment: @JosephMarikle just added it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#nav ul a {
        display: block;
        height:25px;
        padding: 0 20px;/*changeto width for static size*/
        line-height:25px;
        background: rgba(24,24,24,1.0);
        /* text-align:center; */
        border: 1px solid grey;
        border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aunbyw9L/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this corrects your problem but in reality, the only true problem is that you have an explicit height set.  The `height:25px;` is what is causing the versioning numbers to overflow their container.  They are the width they are because of the parent `li`.  block level elements default to `100%`ish width. (There are some differences particularly with padding and if you want to reset block elements back to their default you would use `width:auto`).  All of that unfortunately doesn't help you.  The `position:absolute` elements are trying to match their parent in width.  The two things you can do are remove the `height:25px` and allow `line-height:25px` maintain your height (this will result in all the text being in your `li`'s, but they will only be as wide as the parent `li`), or you can give the `li a`'s `white-space:nowrap`.  I prefer the second approach, personally.  The bugs you may experience are long titles ending up off screen because of the lack of wrapping (obviously).  Here is the rule and a demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/81un9gaa/ (check item 2.2.2)

```
#nav ul a {
    display: block;
    /*height:25px;*/ /* remove this */
    padding: 0 20px;/*changeto width for static size*/
    line-height:25px;
    background: rgba(24,24,24,1.0);
    text-align:center;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;

    /* this one is optional, but I prefer it
       in most cases. */
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!! =)
I also added: #nav ul ul ul li{width: 100%;} to make them all even